# C# Passing method name to parameterizedthreadstart with variable

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2010, pass-by-reference

Okay guys, please don't shoot me down to hard for asking this.

// using System.Threading;

```
    private void startThread()
    {            
        Thread t = new Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart(setOutputBinaryWorker));
        t.Start();
    }
```

This works fine due to the setOutputBinaryWorker being an actual, existing method. However, I'm looking for a way to pass the function name as a variable to the startThread function.

Thanks to my limited C# experience, I suspect it to be possible but cannot seem to figure out how. I can image it should be something like this:

```
// using System.Threading;

    private void startThread(??datatype?? func)
    {            
        Thread t = new Thread(ParameterizedThreadStart(func));
        t.Start();
    }
```

But I cannot figure out what the datatype should be ( heads the use of questionmarks ).
Now, while debugging, the passed function name pops up as

> System.Object Void, setOutputBinaryWorker

which just doesn't give me much to go on. Can these be created? Tried casting the parameter as (object) which doesn't work.

The main idea behind this, is experimenting with a safe gui-thread to write to ui elements in the correct way. 
Now, I've got that part down, using delegated methods it all works just dandy. But when switching to the current approach ( making the method name variable ) I'm just completely lost.
If someone knows an alternative, better, or at least working solution, I'm open to suggestions, big time.

Thanks in advance for your efforts.

Comment: Why don't you just pass in a ParameterizedThreadStart? Also: for the ParameterizedThreadStart version, don't you need to pass a value into Start?

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, and yes i do. In response to your question: That won't work, I need to pass the functions name because it will be wrapped in an external dll.

Comment: What kind of methods are you going to invoke this way? Will they have the same signature and return value?

Comment: The idea is to create a dll file with some generic functions. One of these is the ability to create a gui-thread. The type of those methods will always be void.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The datatype should be a delegate with signature:

void (object) - meaning, a method that doesn't return anything and takes an object parameter

Example:

```
delegate void TestDelegate(object o);

        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TestDelegate custom = SomeMethod;
            ParameterizedThreadStart pts = new ParameterizedThreadStart(custom);
            Thread thread = new Thread(pts);
            thread.Start();
        }

        private void SomeMethod(object o)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hey!");
        }
```

Note that we are passing in a variable of type TestDelegate. This enables you to  pass different methods to the thread at runtime as long as the methods adhere to the delegate signature.

Pair with Reflection:

```
    // assuming class is in same assembly as this method
    Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
    // you can choose to get type from an known object instead
    Type type = assembly.GetType("Test.SomeClass");
    object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(type, null);            
    MethodInfo methodInfo = type.GetMethod("SomeMethod");                        
    object[] parameterValues = new object[] { 1 };            
    methodInfo.Invoke(instance, parameterValues);
```

Just be mindful of performance when using Reflection. If you can, cache the created objects to do away with creating the object using Reflection.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The delegate datatype I do understand. However, correct me if I'm wrong, but SomeMethod still has to be an existing function. The point of the exercise is to eliminate just that. I would like to setup the function so that a delegate method defined in another class may be passed to it to be used with parameterizedThreadStart.

Comment: In comparison. PHP allows function names to be passed as string. Therefore it is completely up to you how and where you define the function. Is something similar possible in C# or is it simply not done to want to do that?

Comment: Does Reflection fit your requirement? I updated my answer to include Reflection.

Answer (score 1):

I would use lambda expression

```
Thread t =new Thread(
 () =>
  {
    function(anyparameter);
  }
 ).Start();
```

Comment: Okay, I'm interested, but what does this do exactly? In which way does it replace my code?

Comment: @Digitalis instead of using ParameterizedThreadStart,u can just pass the parameter

Comment: Okay. I'm sorry, I believe this is a bit above my paygrade. You're saying that the option I originally requested isn't possible? Or is this simply faster / better / newer?

Comment: @Digitalis you asked for alternative and this is a one

Comment: True that, only I'd like to understand what I'm coding :) Don't get me wrong, I'm thankful for your answers and time, but how does it work?

Comment: @Digitalis it passes the function via lambda expression, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397687.aspx . This helps u understand lambda expressions

Comment: Okay, I have played with this a bit and I cannot get it to work. The problem being, how does one use this lambda structure? Anyone?

Comment: Thanks for your reply but my personal opinion and understanding of the lambda expression leads me to believe that it will work confusing in this situation. Thanks again for your efforts though, and your right, it does work, just not for me in this case.